# Check for available app downloads on Apple TV

Tags: ios, install, ios-appstore, appletv

Several months ago I bought Sonic the Hedgehog (1) on iOS and was very happily surprised to see it appear on my 4th gen Apple TV also. Now I bought Sonic 2 but it hasn't shown up on the Apple TV yet.

I checked that it is [one of the Sonic games with an Apple TV counterpart](https://www.google.co.jp/amp/s/www.engadget.com/amp/2016-03-17-sonic-apple-tv.html), so it is possible.

In the Apple TV menu I went to Settings > Apps > Automatically Install Apps and switched it to "On" (I guess it was off when I purchased Sonic 2, but not 1). I then restarted the Apple TV but no new apps appeared.

I also tried switching accounts and switching back, hoping that would prompt tvOS to check for available downloads, but it didn't.

How can I get iOS apps with an Apple TV version to install on Apple TV? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open up the App Store on your Apple TV, then go to the Purchased tab, there’s a section titled Not on This Apple TV that will list apps you’ve purchased (even for free) that are not installed. You can select it there and then download it for free. Alternatively you can search for it on the App Store and download it for free from there. Make sure you’re signed in with the same Apple ID you used to purchase it previously.